# Regex get from character to whitespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I'm trying to pull the username from a post in rails. I thought the best way to do this would be using regex and pull from the @ to the next whitespace character which would give me the username.

e.g in the string:

```
'@stackoverflow is good for help'
```

I would be able to pull from the @ to the next whitespace character giving me the string `'stackoverflow'`

My regex skills are a little lacking so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\S` to match any non-whitespace character, for example:

```
(?<=@)\S*
```

Will match any sequence of zero or more non-whitespace characters which appear immediately after a `@` character. The `(?<=…)` creates a lookbehind assertion, so the `@` will not be included in the match.

[**Demonstration**](http://rubular.com/r/q0pBXral1F)

Alternatively, you could use:

```
@(\S*)
```

This will match a `@`, followed by zero or more non-whitespace characters, captured in group 1.

[**Demonstration**](http://rubular.com/r/Vs921ngReT)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
regex = /@(\S*)/
```

`\S` here matches all non-whitespace character.

Comment: This works thanks. But it returns me the @ as well with the string.

Comment: @jckly Everything after the `@` is captured in group 1, so you'd have to extract that group (or just get a substring with `[1..-1]`)

Comment: Well, it shouldn't.
`'@asdf asdfg'.match(/@(\S*)/)[1] => 'asdf'`